# /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory on rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Earlier my application was using ruby1.9.1 even though I had ruby 1.9.3. And for this reason I removed ruby 1.9.1  from by system and set rvm to use ruby 1.9.3.

Now When I type which ruby I get :

```
/home/sachin/.rvm/bin/ruby
```

And ruby -v I'm getting:

```
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
```

But When I'm starting my rails application with `rails s`

I'm getting this error:

```
 /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
```

Even though I have set

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby 1.9.3
```

in my script/rails file.

Any idea what could be missing?

Comment: I am not an expert in Ruby, but this seems like an issue related to setting up your environment. Can you post the result of "whereis ruby" ?

Comment: @SaifAsif  It isn't showing anything Just  "ruby:"

Comment: It seems your environment is messed up a bit. It should have given you at-least one path like "/usr/bin/ruby" or something like that. Can you remove all the ruby installations in the system do a fresh installation of it ?

Comment: Also can you change the syntax of your script to `#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.3` (remove the space between ruby and version)

Comment: Did you guys happen to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here's what I did :

```
root@occulti : Sinatra_Ruby $ heroku login
/usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.0: No such file or directory
root@occulti : Sinatra_Ruby $ which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
```

I opened the file `/usr/bin/heroku` and then added the ruby path given by the `which ruby` command, which is (in my case) : `#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby`

Hope it helps.